# indexPath.row returns last visible cell, and didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have an NSArray and a tableView with some buttons whose title is the string in the array at the current indexpath row

```
- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath {

 _selectedRow = indexpath.row;
 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"customCell";
 cell = [myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
 }

 [cell.playButton setTitle:array[indexpath.row] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

 return cell;

}
```

Button titles are well shown.

Now I have some mp3 files whose names are the same as the strings in the array, and I want to play the file corresponding to the selected cell.

```
fileToPlay = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", array[_selectedRow]]; ofType:@"mp3"];
```

What's happening here is that the file played is always the one corresponding to the last visible cell in the table.

I also have

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath {
 _selectedRow = indexpath.row;
}
```

but If I try to print _selectedRow here, nothing appears in the log.

When I click on a cell in the table, it doesn't seem selected (it's not gray colored).

dataSource and delegate are also well connected to the tableview.

**UPDATE**

I found out that if I click on the button, it's like I'm not clicking on the selected row. if I click on the cell (outside the button), the indexPath.row is correct.

Comment: Try this: 
set   myGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchInView  to false

Comment: why you are adding _selectedRow = indexpath.row; in cellForRowAtIndex?

Comment: Are you sure that `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is even getting called when you select the cell?  It may not be getting selected at all, which will leave your `_selectedRow` as the last cell that was loaded (bottom if you are scrolling down, top if you are scrolling up...).

Comment: better did select you can use method like this on button click [cell.playButton setTag:indexPath.row];
 [cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: I found out that if I click on the button, it's like I'm not clicking on the selected row. if I click on the cell (outside the button), the indexPath.row is correct.

Comment: i updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the following line from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
 _selectedRow = indexpath.row;
```

You are setting the `_selectedRow` value each time the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called,which is when each cell is drawn and explains why the value of the last cell is being taken.

Comment: yes, i was just trying. but the probem here is that when i click on the button in the cell, i'm not actuallyu clicking n the cell, so the selectedRow isn't updating. if i click on the cell (outside the button), it is.

Comment: Do you really need a button? It seems like the button is consuming the touch event. Can you try setting
button.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

on the button inside the cell?

Comment: i need it to play the audio

Comment: Can't you use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to play the audio?

Comment: yes, i just add _selectedRow = indexPath.row; [self listenCoro]; to didSelectRowAtIndexPath . thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set Code:

```
 - (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath {
 cell.playButton.tag = indexpath.row;
[cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPlay:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
- (IBAction)btnPlay:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    _selectedRow = btn.tag;
}
```

You are select selection color for touch color set.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1) set myGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchInView to false... maybe your touches are getting in way. (It's a common issue when you may have gesture recognizers)

2) In your tableView's attribute's inspector, set Selection to singleton. That solved my issue

3) set this : [tableView setAllowsSelection:YES];

Comment: okay do this: set a breakpoint at didselectrowatindexpath. Check if the method gets called or not

Comment: The problem is, if didselectrowatindexpath is not being called, then the value of _selectedrow isnt changing, and thus what you select is not what they highlight